Autenticación de Google en .NET con Swagger
Estoy tratando de implementar en mi API hecha en .NET8.0 la autenticación con Google.
Voy a contar los pasos que he dado para dar el mayor contexto:


Lo primero fue crear un proyecto web.
Lo segundo fue crear en Google Cloud el ID de cliente OAuth 2.0.
En la pantalla de consentimiento agregué 3 cuentas para testing.

Después pasé a la configuración de mi API en .NET siguiendo la documentación que aporta microsoft:
Configuré mi appsettings.json con la configuración que indicaba la documentación.
  "Authentication": {
    "Google": {
      "ClientId": "<cliente id>",
      "ClientSecret": "<secreto cliente>"
    }
  },

Creé un DTO para gestionar la autenticación de google:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Business.DTOs.AppConfigs
{
    public class AppAuthenticationConfig
    {
        [Required]
        public string ClientId { get; set; } = String.Empty;

        [Required]
        public string ClientSecret { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    }
}

Después creé una extensión para inyectar servicios de autenticación:
using Business.DTOs.AppConfigs;

namespace Presentation.API.Extensions
{
    public static class AuthenticationCofigurationExtension
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddAuthenticationConfigurationExtension(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
        {
            services.Configure<AppAuthenticationConfig>(config.GetSection("Authentication:Google"));
            services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
            {
                googleOptions.ClientId = config["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
                googleOptions.ClientSecret = config["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
            });

            return services;
        }
    }
}

Dentro del Program.cs configuré todas las inyecciones de dependencias de la misma manera:
using Business.DTOs;
using Presentation.API.Extensions;
using Presentation.VMs;
using Serilog;

WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Configure Serilog
builder.Host.UseSerilog(
    (hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
    {
        loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration);
    }
);

builder.Services.AddCustomParamsApplicationConfiguration(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddAuthenticationConfigurationExtension(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddSecurityConfiguration(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddCorsConfiguration(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddDataBaseContextConfiguration(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddBusinessServices(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MapperProfileDTO).Assembly, typeof(MapperProfileVM).Assembly);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddLoggerConfiguration(builder.Configuration);

WebApplication app = builder.Build();
AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors("StrictOrigin");

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

// Check migrations and seed the database
app.CheckMigrationsAndSeedDB();

app.Run();

Después en el servicio pido la verificación del token que se pasa:
 public async Task<LoginResponseDTO?> GoogleLogin(GoogleLoginDTO login)
 {
     try
     {

         GoogleJsonWebSignature.Payload? payload = await VerifyGoogleToken(login.Token);
         if (payload == null)
         {
             return null; // invalid token
         }

         User? user = await _unitOfWork.Users.GetSingleAsync(u => u.Email == payload.Email);

         if (user == null) // Darlo de alta automáticamente
         {
             user = new User
             {
                 UserName = payload.Email,
                 Email = payload.Email,
                 EmailConfirmedAt = DateTime.UtcNow
             };

             user.Role = await _unitOfWork.Roles.GetDefaultRole();
             user.RoleId = user.Role.Id;

             _unitOfWork.Users.Add(user);
             await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
         }

         string token = GetToken(user.UserName);
         string refreshToken = GenerateRefreshToken();

         user.RefreshToken = refreshToken;
         user.RefreshTokenExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7);

         await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

         return new LoginResponseDTO
         {
             Token = token,
             RefreshToken = refreshToken,
             Expiration = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(_appSecurityConfig.HoursTokenExpiration),
             UserId = user.Id,
             UserName = user.UserName,
             Email = user.Email,
             RoleName = user.Role.Name,
             IsEmailConfirmed = user.EmailConfirmedAt.HasValue
         };
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
         throw;
     }
 }

 private async Task<GoogleJsonWebSignature.Payload?> VerifyGoogleToken(string idToken)
 {
     try
     {
         GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidationSettings? settings = new GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidationSettings()
         {
             Audience = new List<string> { _appAuthenticationConfig.ClientId }
         };
         GoogleJsonWebSignature.Payload payload = await GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(idToken, settings);
         return payload;
     }
     catch (InvalidJwtException ijEx)
     {
         Console.WriteLine($"Invalid JWT: {ijEx.Message}");
         if (ijEx.InnerException != null)
         {
             Console.WriteLine($"Inner Exception: {ijEx.InnerException.Message}");
         }
         return null;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine($"Token validation failed: {ex.Message}");
         return null;
     }
 }

Para obtener el token utilizo la web OAuth 2.0 Playground:

Dicho id_token es el que pasaré como parámetro para iniciar la autenticación, pero me sale todo el rato el mismo error:
Google.Apis.Auth.InvalidJwtException: 'JWT contains untrusted 'aud' claim.' y es porque en vez de contrastar el ClientId del OAuth2.0 previamente configurado está obteniendo el ID de la cuenta de correo y por tanto obtengo siempre token inválido.
¿Puede ser por swagger? ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?
Gracias de antebrazo.
